# Error Reading Characters of Strings [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, string, ifstream

```
 void showUserData() {
    ifstream file;
        file.open("bmi.txt");

        string BMIname;
        string BMInames[5];

        string BMIweight;
        string BMIweights[5];

        string BMIheight;
        string BMIheights[5];

        string Bmi;
        string Bmis[5];

        string BMIclassification;
        string BMIclassifications[5];

        file.close();
        file.open("bmi.txt");

        int skip2 = 4;
        int count5 = 0;
        int count6 = 0;
        int count7 = 0; 
        int count8 = 0;
        int count9 = 0;

        while (file >> BMInames[count5])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 names
        {
            count5++;
        }

        file.close();
        file.open("bmi.txt");

        file.ignore(1000, '\n');

        while (file >> BMIheights[count6])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 heights
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < skip2; i++)
                file >> BMIheight; //For each time i is less that 4, then output the names read from the file to the console
            count6++;

        }

        file.close();
        file.open("bmi.txt");

        file.ignore(1000, '\n'); 
        file.ignore(1000, '\n');

        while (file >> BMIweights[count7])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 weights
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < skip2; i++)

            file >> BMIweight; //For each time i is less that 4, then output the names read from the file to the console
            count7++;

        }

        file.close();
        file.open("bmi.txt");

        file.ignore(1000, '\n');
        file.ignore(1000, '\n');
        file.ignore(1000, '\n');

        while (file >> Bmis[count8])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 bmi's
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < skip2; i++)
                file >> Bmi; //For each time i is less that 4, then output the names read from the file to the console
            count8++;
        }

        file.close();
        file.open("bmi.txt");

        file.ignore(1000, '\n');
        file.ignore(1000, '\n');
        file.ignore(1000, '\n');
        file.ignore(1000, '\n');

        while (file >> BMIclassifications[count9])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 classifications
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < skip2; i++)
                file >> BMIclassification; //For each time i is less that 4, then output the names read from the file to the console
            count9++;
        }

        file.close();

        int choice;

        cout << "Which users history would you like to see?" << endl;
        cin >> choice;


        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Name: " << BMInames[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Height: " << BMIheights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Weight: " << BMIweights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "BMI: " << Bmis[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Classification: " << BMIclassifications[choice - 1] << '\n'; //Output all of the files collected and stored in the names array
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Name: " << BMInames[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Height: " << BMIheights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Weight: " << BMIweights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "BMI: " << Bmis[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Classification: " << BMIclassifications[choice - 1] << '\n'; //Output all of the files collected and stored in the names array
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Name: " << BMInames[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Height: " << BMIheights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Weight: " << BMIweights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "BMI: " << Bmis[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Classification: " << BMIclassifications[choice - 1] << '\n'; //Output all of the files collected and stored in the names array
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Name: " << BMInames[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Height: " << BMIheights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Weight: " << BMIweights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "BMI: " << Bmis[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Classification: " << BMIclassifications[choice - 1] << '\n'; //Output all of the files collected and stored in the names array
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Name: " << BMInames[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Height: " << BMIheights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Weight: " << BMIweights[choice - 1] << '\n' << "BMI: " << Bmis[choice - 1] << '\n' << "Classification: " << BMIclassifications[choice - 1] << '\n'; //Output all of the files collected and stored in the names array
            break;
        }
    }
```

So i'm making a program where I have to read user's bmi data from a txt file [bmi file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z56dE.png)

I'm reading in the user's names, heights, weights, bmi's and classifications using ifstream. I'm using file.ignore to ignore lines in the file to read different pieces of data. However, when I press run, I keep getting the error: Error Reading Characters of Strings.

I've used this method to read data from a file before and it worked fine. But it doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: Did you debug to see where exactly is the error generating from?

Comment: It stores all the user information in an array. But it just gives me the same error. It's only when I call the function. It doesn't want to output the data from the array

Comment: what function? Please create [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, the whole code posted above is in a function. Which is then called in the main

Comment: then debug inside the function?